# Cron jobs in wordpress

Tags: plugins, backup

I have a site in WordPress, perfectly configured, but I can not configure the CRON for it and its plugins. The WordPress Cron is enabled, but the following message appears in the crontab of the plugins.
"** WARNING: Next run time has passed.It should have run 50 minutes ago.Cron problem? **"
What worries me most is the BackupBuddy plugin, I can not run out of backups. Backups only work with cron.
Can you help me? Does this ok? I do not have experience with backupBuddy and cron jobs.
Thanks

Comment: In order to use cron, WordPress need to make a HTTP request to iself. then you have to verify if HTTP requests are allowed in PHP and if direct requests are possible, that means without htpasswd protection.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove backupbuddy and just not use it at all. You don't need it. You can create a cron job for different types of backups, whether database, your files, etc.

To list current cron jobs on your server, the command is `crontab -l` and set up a new cron job, its `crontab -e`.

Setting up a cron job is easy, what you need to learn is the times you need it to run. It would look something like this:

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW /bin/sh command > /dev/null 2 > & 1
* * * * * /bin/sh command > /dev/null 2 > & 1
```